# Git shows no branches

Tags: git

I've created a bare repository than cloned it. When I do `git branch -a` nothing is showed. How come I don't even see the default `master` branch? Although `git bash` shows the following:

```
/some/path/project (master)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have probably cloned an empty repository, there is nothing for the `master` branch to point to.

- A `branch` points to a `commit`
- A `commit` points to a `tree`
- A `tree` lists some `blobs` or other `trees`

Comment: You're right, after making a commit the master branch is now displayed. So in order for a branch to be displayed there must be at least one commit, right?

Comment: Yes, check my edit for how git stores brief explanation of how git stores data.

Answer (score 1):

For the repository to show branches, you first need to add the files and commit. Use `git add -a` for adding all files or use `git add <file_name>` to add a particular file. After adding the file, use `git commit -a` to commit all added files. It will take you to the vim editor where you must write the commit message, and exit the editor after saving. Once this is done, you will be able to see the branch *master*. To confirm type `git branch` and it will now show you all the branches. Now, you can add other branches by using the command `git branch <new_branch_name>`.